# Unable to get object from JSON response using Jersey Client API and Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-client

I have a test method that uses the JAX-RS Client API to call a service. When I run this code:

```
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

List<Thing> list = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Thing>>() {});
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type interface java.util.List
```

I have the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency configured correctly (it is used by the service I'm calling), and the project runs on WildFly 10.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Thing> = (List<Thing>)mapper.readValue(response.getEntityInputStream(), List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was apparently caused by a conflict between Jersey and RESTEasy.

I couldn't find a way to disable RESTEasy in WildFly 10, so I ended up removing all Jersey dependencies from my project.

Since I'm only using JAX-RS standard features, it worked fine.